Node.js v20.14.0, Object.<anonymous> with Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
After writing code in express framework I am getting error for route level
Full error
D:\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:216
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<computed> [as post] (D:\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:216:15)
    at proto.<computed> [as post] (D:\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:521:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\server\routes\auth.js:8:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\server\routes\index.js:5:20)

Node.js v20.14.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...


auth.js:8:8 code
const router = require('express').Router();
const { regController, logController } = require('../controller/auth');

router.post('/reg', regController);
router.post('/log', logController);

module.exports = router;

index.js:5:20
const router = require('express').Router();

const authRoutes = require('./auth');

const usersRoutes = require('./users')
const authenticate = require('../middleware/authenticate');

router.use('/auth', authRoutes);
router.use('/users', authenticate, usersRoutes);

module.exports = router;

controller/auth.js
const { regService, logService } = require('../service/auth');

const registerController = async (req, res, next) => {
    //console.log(req.body);
    const { name, email} = req.body;

    if (!name || !email {     
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid Data" })
    }

    try {
        const user = await regService({ name, email })
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "User created successfully", user })
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
};

const loginController = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body
    //console.log(req.body);
    try {
        const token = await logService({ email, password });
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "Login Successfull", token });
    } catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
};

module.export = { regController, logController };

I wrote auth.js & index.js file so many times, and check the controller code, also upgrade the node version, unfortunately error is the same for all time

I think this is because you are trying to export the functions from controller/auth.js, but you have typo in your export statement. You are defining your functions as registerController and loginController, whereas in the export statement you are trying to export regController and logController. To fix this you can either rename your function names to 'regController' and 'logController' in the function definitions. Or you may update your export statement to
module.exports = { regController: registerController, logController: loginController };


Checking your answer
